# how to redirect to my ionic App from an external service after successful payment

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to integrate payment in my app and is working well by redirecting users to the payment gateway site for users to make the payment. The issue I am having is how to redirect back to my app after a successful or failed transaction. Please what will `the-callback-url` to my ionic App be in this code?

```
if(event.url.indexOf('https://your-callback-url') != -1) {
      if(this.rave.paymentStatus('url') == 'failed') {  
         console.log("failed Message");
           }else {
        console.log("Transaction Successful");
     }
}
```

Comment: what service are you using to compelete transaction? paypal? mastercard? visa?

Comment: flutterwave payment gateway